# Updating second row on an SOOrder

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have an SOOrder with multiple lines and I am trying to update both of the lines and allocations in a loop. I can update the first records split Qty and OrderQty on the line, but when the second line comes along it updates the allocation correctly but the line OrderQty does get changed. If I do this same logic on an order with just one line it works as expected.

```
protected void _(Events.RowPersisted<INLotSerialStatus> e)
{
  var soOrderEntryMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();           

  var existingSHSoLineLineSplits = soOrderEntryMaint.Select<SOLineSplit>()
    .Where(w => w.OrderType == SSIConstants.OrderTypes.SH &&
                w.LotSerialNbr == lotSerial &&
                w.SiteID == siteID)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Qty)
    .ToList();

  // 1) loop through each split and get the SoOrder and the SoLine
  foreach (SOLineSplit soLineSplit in existingSHSoLineLineSplits)
  {
    if (remaining <= 0) return;
    
    // 2) set SoOrder and SOLine SoLineSpLit as current
    soOrderEntryMaint.splits.Current = soLineSplit;

    var soOrderNumber = soOrderEntryMaint.Select<SOOrder>()
                        .First(w => w.OrderType == SSIConstants.OrderTypes.SH &&
                                    w.OrderNbr == soLineSplit.OrderNbr);

   soOrderEntryMaint.Document.Current = soOrderNumber;

   var soLine = soOrderEntryMaint.Select<SOLine>()
                 .First(w => w.OrderType == SSIConstants.OrderTypes.SH &&
                             w.OrderNbr == soLineSplit.OrderNbr &&
                             w.LineNbr == soLineSplit.LineNbr);
    soOrderEntryMaint.Transactions.Current = soLine;

    // 3) decrement SOLineSplit
    // 4) decrement the SoLine
    // 5) decrement remaining
    if (soLineSplit.Qty > remaining)
    {
      soLineSplit.Qty -= remaining;
      soLine.Qty -= remaining;
      remaining = 0;
    }
    else if (soLineSplit.Qty <= remaining)
    {
       var qtyToRemove = soLineSplit.Qty;
       soLine.Qty = soLine.Qty - qtyToRemove <= 0
                     ? 0
                     : soLine.Qty - qtyToRemove;
                      soLineSplit.Qty = 0;
       remaining -= qtyToRemove ?? 0 ;
    }

    // 6) update and save.Press
    // 7) Maint clear
    soOrderEntryMaint.splits.Update(soLineSplit);
    soOrderEntryMaint.Transactions.Update(soLine);
    soOrderEntryMaint.Actions.PressSave();
    soOrderEntryMaint.Clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would try to change is the order in which you set currents. Set the SOOrder first, then SOLine, and only after that the SOLineSplit.

Comment: Where is the RowPersisted event? Row persisted runs for insert, update, delete and also has transtatus so it will run multtiple times for the same change and possible for abort but your code will still update sales orders. In general, I would avoid creating a graph instance in any event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Save and Clear actions are in the for loop. Maybe if you move them outside this will work correctly?

After the first iteration, the code is saving and clearing the SOOrderEntry graph.

Answer (score 0):

I went further into the code and I found that an existing update event was found that was canceling further processing. The first one would always work and when that Cancel was called it was not being removed. I ended up moving the "var soOrderEntryMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance(); " to the end of the loop so that way any events that were added will not be there on the next item. May not be the prettiest way but it works.